# How to Create a Floating Widget That Can Float Outside of the Website Environment in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, pip, widget

I'm working on a project where I need to implement a floating widget that can overlay content not only within the website but also outside of it,

The widget should stay on top of every application window. It should be draggable and interactable by the user.

similar to the "Stop Sharing" widget in Google Meet. For reference, here's a screenshot of the Google Meet widget:

[image: floating image]

I've explored the pip mode in HTML, but it seems to be limited to video elements. I'm currently using React for my project, and I'm unsure about the best approach to achieve this functionality.

Could someone provide guidance on how to create such a floating widget in React that has the ability to float over content both within and outside of the website environment? Any code examples or pointers to relevant libraries would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Using [react-draggable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-draggable)

```
import React from 'react';
import Draggable from 'react-draggable'; // Import react-draggable
import './FloatingWidget.css'; // You'll create this CSS file

const FloatingWidget = () => {
  return (
    <Draggable>
      <div className="floating-widget">
        {/* Widget content goes here */}
      </div>
    </Draggable>
  );
};

export default FloatingWidget;
```

```
.floating-widget {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1000; /* Adjust the z-index to ensure it appears above other content */
}
```

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import FloatingWidget from './FloatingWidget';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {/* Other content */}
      <FloatingWidget />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks the comment, but I need a system wide draggable component, that can be shown over other apps as well. I think your example component will only show inside website not over other apps.

Comment: ohh i see, but creating a system-wide draggable component that can be shown over other apps on a user's desktop is a different task altogether and generally requires the development of a standalone desktop application. This is often platform-specific, as it involves interacting with the underlying operating system

Comment: I initially had the same thought, but after looking at Google Meet's "stop sharing" widget, I'm wondering about the way they made it work. I just need exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

It’s not possible as of now. Google chrome is an installed application and interacts with OS and hence can create floating widgets.

You can check Document Picture in Picture api and see if it helps.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Picture-in-Picture_API